# GET all issues from JIRA Project using JIRA REST API with python

Tags: python-3.x, jira-rest-api

I am using the JIRA REST API to pull all the issues in one specific project but am having trouble getting more than 100 issues. There are ~ 450 issues total I want to get. I'm still fairly new to python and not quite understanding the pagination and have looked at similar posts but didn't see a solution. I'm using search for issues using JQL(GET). Here is my current code that gives me 100 issues (ORDER BY key DESC), but I still need to get the next 300+ issues as well. Many thanks in advance.

```
baseurl = 'www.baseurl.com'

endpoint = 'endpoint'

def main_request(baseurl, endpoint):
    auth = HTTPBasicAuth(email, token)

    headers = {
        'Accept': 'application/json'
    }

    query = {
        'jql': 'project=projectKey',
        'startAt': 0,
        'maxResults': 100
    }

    r = requests.get(
        baseurl + endpoint,
        headers=headers,
        params=query,
        auth=auth
    )

    return r.json()

def parse_json(response):
    issuelist = []
    for item in response['issues']:
        issue = {
            'Key': item['key'],
            'Summary': item['fields]['summary']
        }

       issuelist.append(issue)
    return issuelist
    
data = main_request(baseurl, endpoint)
print(parse_json(data))
```

Comment: why don't you use [atlassian python api](https://github.com/atlassian-api/atlassian-python-api)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply make the startAt value as a parameter.  Make a recursive call till the response has nothing in the response ie. an empty array.
So the call will be `main_request(baseurl, endpoint, startAt)`

And in the loop , `startAt = startAt + maxResults`
and then `data.append(main_request(baseurl, endpoint, startAt)`

Comment: Perfect thank you! Worked great, I am able to pull all the issues now